# Ruby get user input, add to array. Verify if user input matches array of objects

Tags: ruby, object, hash, include

I have a small method that will be called on a initialized 'Order' class object, to get user input, asking them what item they would like to add from a menu to their order. The method is:

```
def add_to_order
    @order = []
    while true
      puts "Item:"
      @item = gets.chomp
      break if @item.empty?
      puts "Qty?"
      @qty = gets.chomp
      @order << [@item, @qty]
    end
  end
```

I have the menu stored in an array, as a 'hash' of objects, created previously from initializing new objects from a class called 'Dish'. These were added to an instance variable called @menu, which is:

```
 @menu=
  [[#<Dish:0x007fa1f8953b10 @dish={:name=>"Chicken Stew", :price=>4.5}>,
    #<Dish:0x007fa1f883daf0 @dish={:name=>"Beef & Ale Pie", :price=>5.0}>,
    #<Dish:0x007fa1f89d86f8 @dish={:name=>"Chicken & Leek Pie", :price=>4.0}>,
    #<Dish:0x007fa1f8b5b048 @dish={:name=>"Vegetable Pie", :price=>3.5}>,
    #<Dish:0x007fa1f8d03378 @dish={:name=>"Fish Pie", :price=>5.5}>,
    #<Dish:0x007fa1f8df1c08 @dish={:name=>"Chips", :price=>2.0}>,
    #<Dish:0x007fa1f9993a70 @dish={:name=>"Mushy Peas", :price=>1.5}>]]
```

My question is - when getting user input, how can I check whether or not the item they type in, is on the list contained in the @menu, when this @menu is not a normal array, but if more an 'array of object information? I tried the following but it did not work.

```
def add_to_order
    @order = []
    while true
      raise 'ERROR!' if @menu[0].include?(@item)
      .......
end
```

Comment: In your code `@menu` is an array containing a second array of Dish objects. Why do you need the second nested array?

You could take a look at the Hash class for creating `@menu`: it lets you build key => value pairs lists; which you can easily check for the presence of particular key in it, with Hash#has_key? instance method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` (or its alias `detect`) that takes an block:

```
@menu[0].find { |dish| dish.name == @item }
```

This would return the first dish from the menu which name matches `@item` or `nil` if there wasn't a matching dish.

Hint: You might want to consider storing your menu in a hash instead of an array, because a hash would allow faster lookups.

Comment: Minor thing, you wrote ``disk`` instead of ``dish`` in your code.

Comment: cheers for that - yes, not withstanding the typo, each time I try it is comes up with an error `undefined method `[]' for #<Menu:0x007f961b9392f8>`

Comment: undefined method `[]` for `Menu`? There is no `Menu` class in your example. I what line does this error happen? Is your `@menu` really an array that contains an array, that contains hashes (what seems a bit inefficient)?